# Bundle on Kotlin

Tags: android, database, kotlin, navigation, bundle

I have a problem with the `bundle()` function. Consider that I have fragments A, B and C. I want to send data from fragment A to fragment C. I just want to send data from A to C and switch from page A to page B.

[This is my A page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hq0W.png)
[This is my C page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXMhS.png)

On A page I write navigate to dateaction. But when I run it navigate to C page. Why?

```
binding.nextdate.setOnClickListener {
       nextdateaction()
       sendbundle()
}
```

FRAGMENT A

```
package com.example.rebolutbank.features.account

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Patterns
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.text.isDigitsOnly
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.rebolutbank.R
import com.example.rebolutbank.databinding.FragmentSignUpBinding
import com.google.firebase.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.auth.auth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.firestore
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class SignUpFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentSignUpBinding
    private val firestore = Firebase.firestore
    val viewModel : SignUpViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentSignUpBinding.inflate(inflater)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        signUp()

        binding.nextdate.setOnClickListener {
           nextdateaction()
            sendbundle()
        }



        return binding.root
    }
    private fun sendbundle(){
        val username = binding.nameuser.text.toString()
        val lastname = binding.lastnameuser.text.toString()
        val country = binding.usercountry.text.toString()

        val passCodeFragment = PassCodeFragment()
        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putString("username",username)
            putString("lastname",lastname)
            putString("usercountry",country)
        }
        passCodeFragment.arguments = bundle
    }
    private fun signUp(){
        binding.nameuser.setOnFocusChangeListener{_,focused->
            if(!focused){
                binding.nameuserlayout.helperText = valid_name_lastname()

            }
        }

        binding.lastnameuser.setOnFocusChangeListener{_, focused->
            if(!focused){
                binding.lastnameuserlayout.helperText = valid_name_lastname()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun nextdateaction(){

        if (binding.nameuser.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
            binding.anytxt2.text = "Add your Name"
            binding.anytxt2.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        }
        else if (binding.lastnameuser.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
            binding.anytxt2.text = "Add your Lastname"
            binding.anytxt2.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        }
        else if(binding.usercountry.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
            binding.anytxt2.text = "Add your Country"
            binding.anytxt2.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        }
        else{
            var action = SignUpFragmentDirections.actionSignUpFragmentToBirthDateFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)

        }

    }

    private fun valid_name_lastname() : String? {

        val nameText = binding.nameuser.text.toString()
        val lastnameText = binding.lastnameuser.text.toString()


        fun isAlpha(input: String): Boolean {
            return input.all { it.isLetter() }
        }

        if (!isAlpha(nameText) || !isAlpha(lastnameText)) {
            return "Use only alpha"
        }
        // Function to check if a string consists only of alphabetic characters
        return null
    }
}
```

FRAGMENT C

```
package com.example.rebolutbank.features.account

import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.rebolutbank.databinding.FragmentPassCodeBinding
import com.google.firebase.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException
import com.google.firebase.auth.auth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.firestore
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class PassCodeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentPassCodeBinding
    private val editTexts = arrayOfNulls<EditText>(6)
    private val firestore = Firebase.firestore

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentPassCodeBinding.inflate(inflater)
        var editTextIds = arrayOf(
            binding.passcode1,
            binding.passcode2,
            binding.passcode3,
            binding.passcode4,
            binding.passcode5,
        )

        for (i in editTextIds.indices) {
            editTexts[i] = editTextIds[i]
            setEditTextListener(i, editTextIds[i])
        }

        binding.nextcarddesign.setOnClickListener {
            val action = PassCodeFragmentDirections.actionPassCodeFragmentToCardDesignFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
            useradddata()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun setEditTextListener(index: Int, editText: EditText) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                if (s?.length == 1) {
                    // Move focus to the next EditText if a digit is entered
                    moveFocusToNextEditText(index)
                }
            }
        })
    }

private fun useradddata () {
    val arguments = arguments
    val username = arguments?.getString("username")
    val lastname = arguments?.getString("lastname")
    val country = arguments?.getString("usercountry")

    val userdocument = firestore.collection("USERS").document(id.toString())
    userdocument.set(
        mapOf(
            "username" to username,
            "lastname" to lastname,
            "country" to country,
        )
    )
}

    private fun moveFocusToNextEditText(index: Int) {
        if (index < editTexts.size - 1) {
            // Move focus to the next EditText
            editTexts[index + 1]?.requestFocus()
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

FRAGMENT B

```
package com.example.rebolutbank.features.account

import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.rebolutbank.R
import com.example.rebolutbank.databinding.FragmentBirthDateBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Locale

@AndroidEntryPoint
class BirthDateFragment : Fragment() {

    private val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentBirthDateBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentBirthDateBinding.inflate(inflater)

        binding.dateday.setOnClickListener {
            showDatePicker()
        }

        binding.datemonth.setOnClickListener {
            showDatePicker()
        }

        binding.dateyear.setOnClickListener {
            showDatePicker()
        }

        binding.nextmailsign.setOnClickListener {
            gotoMailSignpage()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun showDatePicker() {
        // Create a DatePickerDialog
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
            requireActivity(), {DatePicker, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
                // Create a new Calendar instance to hold the selected date
                val selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance()
                // Set the selected date using the values received from the DatePicker dialog
                selectedDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth)
                // Create a SimpleDateFormat to format the date as "dd/MM/yyyy"
                val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
                // Format the selected date into a string
                val formattedDate = dateFormat.format(selectedDate.time)
                // Update the TextView to display the selected date with the "Selected Date: " prefix
                binding.dateday.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("${formattedDate.subSequence(0,2)}")
                binding.datemonth.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("${formattedDate.subSequence(3,5)}")
                binding.dateyear.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("${formattedDate.subSequence(6,10)}")
            },
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
        // Show the DatePicker dialog
        datePickerDialog.show()
    }

    fun gotoMailSignpage(){
        if (binding.dateday.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
            binding.anytxt2.text = "Add your birthday please"
            binding.anytxt2.setTextColor(Color.RED)
        }
        else{
            val action = BirthDateFragmentDirections.actionBirthDateFragmentToMailSignFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for those 2 methods as well? Without code, it's impossible to identify the real problem.

Comment: Please post the actual text of your code, not a picture. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: I edit it, you can get a code

Answer (score 0):

In the `sendbundle` method, you're instantiating your Fragment class, which you should never do yourself under normal circumstances.
You're setting the `arguments` property of THAT instance only.
Consider using `androidx.navigation` and `navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin` to navigate from one fragment to another with type-safe primitive arguments.  Setup a nav graph, and use the `NavController$navigate` method with the appropriate action generated.

Follow [the official android documentation for navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation).